# Sorting in UNION

Tags: sql, oracle, union

In oracle, does joining two table using UNION implicitly sort data? It appears it does, because as shown in the explain plan window, it shows 'SORT UNIQUE'.

My question is just: by default, by how or what column does it sort?

Answer (score 8):

It does need to enforce uniqueness so it does normally need to do at least a partial sort.
In theory, if it can guarantee uniqueness by another mechanism (eg selecting from specified partitions where the partition key guarantees no overlap) it might not, but I haven't seen an example of that yet.

However it doesn't need to produce sorted output since it can use a hash sort. That is, it sticks all the 'A' words on one bucket, all the 'B' words in the next and so on. The contents of the individual buckets would be sorted but the query may return the results of the 'B' bucket before the 'A' bucket.

Between 9i and 10g Oracle modified the GROUP BY so that it often did a HASH SORT. As a result a lot of people who had taken it for granted that a GROUP BY would imply sorted output were caught out.

Comment: +1, but you probably mean "HASH GROUP BY" instead of "HASH SORT"

Answer (score 4):

The optimizer has a various ways of insuring uniqueness when doing things like `union`, `group by` and `distinct`. And over time as Oracle improves the optimizer, new methods may and hopefully will be introduced. Sometimes that is a sort. But no guarantees it will always be a sort, even if it uses a sort today, it might not tomorrow.

If you need the output sorted, the only way to guarantee that is with an `order by` clause. Without the `order by` Oracle (and for that matter any SQL database) is free to return the rows in any order.

Comment: @cyberkiwi: Sorry to be pedantic, Oracle added an additional way to group. Oracle can still use a plain sort instead of hash tables, if the optimizer believes that plan will execute with fewer resources. I take switch to be the removal of sorting replaced by hash tables. So a query could sort to group/union/etc today and then change to hash table tomorrow, and something not yet built when upgrading to 12gR2 in the year 2013.

Answer (score 0):

yes the sort is implicit in order to remove duplicates since `UNION` does not include duplicates like `UNION ALL`, however if you want a guaranteed sort use `ORDER BY` after all unions to make sure you get the desired sorting

Comment: So this means with out using Order by, there is no default column or process by which the result is sorted? because i thought it is sorted using the arrangement of your select statement, like it is sorted first using the first column you retrieved, then followed by others. Am i thinking wrong about this one?

Comment: -1 "yes the sort is implicit in order to remove duplicates" The optimizer might decide to use a hash table to remove duplicates.

Comment: @Jenny: Yes, you are wrong.  Without an `order by`, the database can return the rows in any order and there is no guarantee that it will return them in the same order every time.  You can verify the former claim for yourself: try `select table_name from dictionary` (or any other sizable system table).